# Different Dbus bindings in server and client

Tags: dbus, qdbus

I am trying to implement Dbus client. Dbus server is actually implemented by a third party and I do not know what bindings does it use (but I guess gdbus). Now can I use QDbus bindings in my client application irrespective of whatever bindings used in Dbus server?
If so, how are the data types (w.r.t. complex data types/user defined structures) managed between server(e.g. glib types) and client(e.g. qt types)? Explanation of this concept would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

All types on the DBus have DBus types, the bindings simply translate them into their own format.  For example, a `uint32` type is an `unsigned int` in C/C++, and in the Java bindings it's a `UInt32`.

Basically, all implementations need to know the wire format of the message.  As long as they understand that format, it doesn't matter what higher-level data type that is translated to.  I wouldn't really call them complex data types, because you can only send basic data types across the bus.